# Import Error: Cannot Import name 'input_reader_pb2'

Tags: python, object-detection, training-data

I am using **Tensorflow Object Detection API** to train my object detection model. I accumulated the dataset, and am going through the

[Training Custom Object Detector - Tensorflow Object Detection API Tutorial](https://pythonprogramming.net/training-custom-objects-tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial/?completed=/creating-tfrecord-files-tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial/)

Everything went fine until I tried to train my dataset. When I run the following line on terminal:

```
python3 train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ 
                 --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 49, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import dataset_builder
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\slim-0.1-py3.6.egg\object_detection\builders\dataset_builder.py", line 27, in <module>
    from object_detection.data_decoders import tf_example_decoder
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\slim-0.1-py3.6.egg\object_detection\data_decoders\tf_example_decoder.py", line 24, in <module>
    from object_detection.protos import input_reader_pb2
ImportError: cannot import name 'input_reader_pb2'
```

I tried searching through sites and comments, but unfortunately still couldn't solve it.

Comment: Can you show us some context around train.py:49 ?

Comment: I used totally same as this : https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/legacy/train.py

Comment: Make sure you followed this it looks like you could be missing something https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your installation of tensorflow object detection api was not complete. You missed the step of protobuf compilation [see here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md#protobuf-compilation). If you look into folder protos under object_detection specifically, there is no file named 'input_reader_pb2', but if you completed the protobuf compilation step, the file will be generated automatically! If your installtion is successful, it should pass the test program [test](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md#testing-the-installation).

Comment: I do have input_reader_pb2 there and I still get this error message

Comment: Did you try testing your installation by running `python object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py`